Synonymize [regional-variation] to [topolect]?
The current tag wiki excerpt of topolect is:

Questions regarding regional variants of the Chinese language.

which is spot-on. The definition of the word "topolect", specifically applied to Chinese, is:

A regional variety of Chinese; especially a lect other than Standard Mandarin.

Assuming that the terms "variants", "variety" and "variation" are equivalent w.r.t. this discussion, from these definitions follows that [regional-variation], for which no tag wiki excerpt is given, is effectively included in [topolect].

A tag synonym seems warranted. However I believe this requires a mod intervention, because of all users who could vote on this synonym (7), only one visited meta in 2020 (Mo.♦), and half of them haven't been seen for years.

This seems like a suitable change to me.  Done: merge/synonymized regional-variation -> topolect.

Noun. topolect (plural topolects) (linguistics, sociolinguistics) The speech form, variety (lect) of a particular place or region. Synonyms: geolect, regiolect, regionalect. (linguistics) A regional variety of Chinese; especially a lect other than Standard Mandarin.

For the record, here are the 17 questions currently tagged regional-variation:

How should I understand the pronunciation of 驾驶证 (jiàshǐ zhèng) as 酱汁儿 (jiàng zhī er)?
Do Chinese speaking different languages use written Chinese to communicate?
Is there a dictionary of standard character variants?
Is the Cantonese diminutive (粒) the same as the Mandarin (子)?
Translation Gaps On Comic Conversation : 1
Hong Kong Cantonese variations
Relative strength of 很笨 and it's variants
Regional variations on 三更半夜
"醡" and "炸" in "醡醬麵" and "炸醬麵"
What qualities does Hong Kong Mandarin have?
Are "身份证" and "身分证" totally interchangeable?
"便利商店" (biànlì shāngdiàn) vs "便利店" (biànlì diàn)
Which IMEs (input method editors) are actually most used in each of PRC, ROC, and Hong Kong?
Is Hakka spoken the same in Guangdong and Taiwan?
Regional pronunciations of standard Mandarin
Does the use of 就 and 便 vary by region?
Which regions use 计算机 for computer?


It may be worth doing the same thing for accent (11 Qs), but let's save that for a future meta post.

are we going to pull the trigger on this?

Oh oops, I forgot about this one.  It still seems fairly reasonable.  Although a score of +1 isn't that strong.

heh, we don't have that big of a participation in meta, we're always treading on 0-3 score ranges.. but if you want to wait this out, no problem for me
